# Obtaining sql permissions on views/tables/etc from command line

Tags: postgresql, psql

These are permissions for ie. `my_view` view

```
pwx1=# \dp my_view
                                    Access privileges
  Schema  |      Name       | Type |   Access privileges   | Column privileges | Policies
----------+-----------------+------+-----------------------+-------------------+----------
 schema_x | my_view         | view | user1=arwdDxt/user1  +|                   |
          |                 |      | user2=arwdDxt/user1  +|                   |
          |                 |      | user3=r/user1         |                   |
```

and I would like to get these grants in sql form like:

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE my_view TO user3;
```

I can get these grants using pgadmin, but want to do it from psql or command line if possible?

Comment: you can start `psql` with the `--echo-hidden` parameter, then you can see the queries that psql uses to generate that display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the ACL information from `pg_class` and use the `aclexplode` function for more pretty presentation:

```
SELECT acl.grantor::regrole AS grantor,
       acl.grantee::regrole AS grantee,
       privilege_type,
       is_grantable
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class AS t
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL aclexplode(t.relacl) AS acl
WHERE t.oid = 'schema_x.my_view'::regclass;
```

In the long run, it is a good idea to learn to read PostgreSQL ACLs.

Comment: Tnx, I guess this is closest as it gets.